# Haskell FFI passing multiple arrays to C

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I have a C function with type

```
int func(int len1, int *array1, int len2, int *array2);
```

that I'd like to call from Haskell. It doesn't modify its contents. I want to pass data from lists. I've been looking through Foreign.Marshal.Array, but I'm quite confused. Either newArray or withArray seems to do what I want, but withArray, for example, takes a function with type

```
Ptr a -> IO b
```

And I'm not quite sure how to deal with that given the two arrays in my function. So far, I have:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "func.h func"
    c_func :: CInt -> Ptr CInt -> CInt -> Ptr CInt -> IO CInt
```

And I'm not sure how to call this. In the documentation (https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Arrays), it just says to read Foreign.Marshall.Array.

Thanks!

Edit: typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `withArray*` functions give you a `Ptr` within the scope of a function. You can write it as a lambda inline, like so:

```
func :: [CInt] -> [CInt] -> IO CInt
func list1 list2 =
    withArrayLen list1 $ \len1 array1 ->
      withArrayLen list2 $ \len2 array2 ->
        c_func (fromIntegral len1) array1 (fromIntegral len2) array2
```

You could also have computed the length separately, for example

```
func list1 list2 =
    withArray list1 $ \array1 ->
      withArray list2 $ \array2 ->
        c_func len1 array1 len2 array2
  where
    len1 = genericLength list1
    len2 = genericLength list2
```

Comment: Thanks! This was easy to understand. My problem now is that the return value is stuck in an IO Monad. Having to trace back through my code everywhere where I use this result is a nightmare. Is there a way that I can pull this result out? As an example I have:

    do
        result <- func l1 l2
        if result == 0 then False else True

But this now has type IO Bool. Is there a way to pull this out to just type Bool?

Comment: Ok, unsafePerformIO does exactly what I want. It seems much vilified, but given that I'm using FFI to C, I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: @EddyJD If `c_func` is pure, using `unsafePerformIO` around it is reasonable. If it has side-effects, you really should thread `IO` everywhere. Among other issues, a function that looks pure to Haskell may be called a greater or fewer number of times than you expect due to optimizations and inlining.